# Python 3 - ¿Asignar un valor es lo mismo que inicializar?

Tags: python, funciones, variables

Cuando creamos una variable
var1 = funcion1()

se supone que una sentencia de asignación no devuelve un valor por si misma? o es diferente en el caso de que sea una función?

Comment: Parece que preguntas algo muy similar a tu anterior [¿Cuál es la manera correcta de referirse a una sentencia de asignación en python?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/174024/83). Por favor, céntrate en resolver esa primera dejando comentarios, editando para clarificar, etc. antes de lanzarte a formular nuevas preguntas.

Comment: es parecida, pero es una cuestión diferente

Comment: Mezclas dos conceptos en el título y en el cuerpo de la pregunta. Respecto al título, sí, asignar un valor a una variable es lo mismo que inicializarla cuando la variable no tenía un valor previo ("inicializar" indica "dar un valor inicial"). Respecto al cuerpo de la pregunta, sí, una sentencia de asignación devuelve un valor por sí misma, que podrías usar para otra asignación. Y es por eso que `a = b = 2` funciona. Pero no veo qué problema te plantea tener `funcion1()` en vez del `2`. Simplemente invocas esa función, y el valor retornado es lo que asignas a la variable.

Comment: gracias por responder @abulafia, me ha quedado un poco mas claro el concepto, lo que pasa es que me confunde un poco por la función input(), pero al parecer lo que hace esta es, llamar a una función del teclado, el programa espera un valor de retorno para continuar su ejecución, y este valor es el que se le asigna a la variable cuando hacemos:
nombre = input()

Comment: @TheRuinedKingRevenge Efectivamente, eso es cierto en general para todas las funciones llamadas "síncronas". Cuando llamas a una función síncrona, el programa que llamó queda a la espera y no puede continuar su ejecución hasta que la función retorne (tanto si ésta retorna realmente un resultado como si retorna `None` que es lo que ocurre cuando la función termina sin haber alcanzado una instrucción `return`). Si estás asignando el resultado a una variable, la asignación no ocurre hasta que la función retorne.

Comment: Hay otro tipo de funciones, llamadas asíncronas, cuyo comportamiento es mucho más difícil de seguir, pero estas funciones no las verás normalmente, pues son nuevas (python 3.6), y requieren de bibliotecas o _frameworks_ que gestionen su ejecución (`asyncio`, por ejemplo). De momento olvídate de ellas pues son tema avanzado.

Comment: @abulafia, perfecto, me quedaron claras mis dudas, muchas gracias! por cierto, sobre las funciones sincronas, ¿son funciones que incluyen una subrutina como el system("pause") en c?, se que son temas avanzados pero me gustaría saber un poco mas